# How to prove $c$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if sum of entries of each row of $A$ is $c$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here $c$ is a scalar and $A$ is a square matrix.

let $x=(1,1,...,1)$ be an eigenvector of $A$, then $Ax=(c,c,...c)=c(1,1...,1)=cx$. And thus $c$is the eigenvalue corresponding to $x$. But I don't know how to formalize the proof. The theorem says "$x$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ if and only if $x\ne0$ and $x\in \ker(T-\lambda I)$". How do you prove $x\in \ker(T-\lambda I)$?

Comment: If what you are trying to prove is what is in the title, then you are done.

Comment: If you have $Ax=\lambda x$ with $x\ne 0$, you have also proven that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and that $x$ is an eigenvector. You do not need the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Your work has shown that $x=(1,\ldots,1)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $c$, so you are finished. This is by **definition** of eigenvector/eigenvalue.

If you would still like to see that the theorem holds, you have also shown this directly... $(A-c I)x = Ax -c x = cx - cx = 0$, so $x \in \ker(A-c I)$.